# android: network security config only in debug version

Tags: android, networking

I'm working on an Android app. For development purpose, I need to specify a network security config as specified in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config). Obviously, it is referenced in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">aaa.bb.cc.dd</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Now, I need to remove this file (and its reference in the manifest too) in the release version of my app. How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply create another `AndroidManifest.xml` and put in in the debug folder structure, something like `app/src/debug`, so this manifest property will be used in debug build, but the real manifest will be used in prod build.

Comment: thanks, it works. Just another question, if you know. this solution implies the manifest duplication. It is possible to have a common definition of manifest and define for release and debug simply a piece to include?

Comment: This is something that i've done for my fabric api key. It might help you        `<meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="${fabricApiKey}" />`
Then in your build.gradle file add variable like 
            `manifestPlaceholders = [fabricApiKey: "someValue"]`

Comment: i want to set/change  domin URL dynamically is it possible?
i.e. domin url will change when i change based url from QA to LIVE

Comment: @SamirSpahic, can you please put entire solution?

Answer (score 14):

Even better than duplicating the `AndroidManifest.xml`, is to create an extra `xml` file in the same on the `app/src/debug` path and Android will automatically recognise that one during a `debug` build.

So, if you currently have a network policy xml file located on:

`app/src/main/res/xml/network_policy.xml`

You would simply create another `xml` resource directory under `app/src/debug` and then another `network_policy.xml` file within that directory:

`app/src/debug/res/xml/network_policy.xml`

And then you just write the network policy for each build variant accordingly.